# cannot ADD file in current directory or in the directory with full path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

#### Current Directory

I cannot ADD file in current directory.

```
$ ls
Dockerfile      id_rsa.pub
```

`$ docker build` result:

```
Step 15 : ADD id_rsa.pub /home/ubuntu/.ssh
stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3c26803340b5ac907bcf6a32dd2c45da9ca98
ee2e4106f9a57a45d244619092b/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: not a directory
```

#### Full Path

I cannot ADD file in the directory with full path.

```
$ ls /Users/weed/.ssh
config      id_rsa.pub      id_rsa      known_hosts
```

`$ docker build` result:

```
Step 15 : ADD /Users/weed/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/ubuntu/.ssh
Users/weed/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with a trailing slash in your `ADD` line

```
ADD /Users/weed/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/ubuntu/.ssh/
```

From the docs:

> If <dest> does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of <src> will be written at <dest>.

So I think `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` is already a directory in the container and the `ADD` command is trying to overwrite it as a file instead of create a new file within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

The files you're trying to add look like SSH public keys. Could you check the permissions on id_rsa.pub , and the permissions on ~/.ssh , with `ls -la` ? It's likely that Docker's build process doesn't have access to either of them.